# Projecting a $v$ onto $v+\epsilon$.

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, noise

Suppose $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\|v\|=1$, and $v^*=v+\epsilon$ be a noise corrupted version, with $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a random vector with entries Gaussian(0,1).

Can I derive an expression for the error obtained when projecting $v$ onto its noise-corrupted self, $\|v-\text{proj}_{v^*}(v)\|$?

My attempt:

$$\|\text{proj}_{v^*}(v)\| = |\frac{ (v, v+\epsilon)}{(v+\epsilon,v+\epsilon)}|\|v+\epsilon\|, $$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{|1+(v,\epsilon)|}{\|v+\epsilon\|}$$

I'd like to take the expected value, but I'm not sure how to simplify then. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you interested in the projection error of $v$ projected on its corrupted version $v^*$, or the projection error of $v^*$ on $v$? The former (your question) will have an involved expression that is not easy to take expectation on, thanks to the ratio with the norm of the corrupted version. It would be far easier for the case of projecting $v^*$ on $v$, as the noise only appears in the numerator of the projection error.

Comment: I actually am interested in the former. I do see your point though.  This specific question arose when I was trying to understand the effect of error on independent variable in linear regression models. There, you are projecting a variable (the left handside) to a noise-corrupted confounding variable, which seems hard to understand. I thought an easier question would be to project a variable onto a noise-corrupted version of itself. But it seems that is difficult too.